# ¿Como calcular salario de empleados de una empresa a través de polimorfismo (JAVASCRIPTS)?

Tags: javascript

El diagrama de clases es el siguiente, Company--(1-*)--Employee--(Polimorfismo)--Executive y Workman.

Se tendría que calcular el total de sueldo que se paga a los empleados de la compañia **"computePayRoll()"**. El sueldo de Executive es de 2000 y el Workman de 1000.

No se como tengo que definir la función que me calcula el salario de cada empleado **"calculateSalary()"**, porque el salario no se puede pasar por el constructor (por eso no se pasa por parámetro en el main), por lo que no puedo modificarlo.

Espero que se entienda, gracias!

```js
(***)

public class Main2 {

/**
 * Main method.
 * @param args Command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
 
    Company company = new Company("Fourth Coffee");
    Employee e;
    e = new Workman("Ewa Trofimova", 1980, "non expert");
    company.addEmployee(e);
    e = new Workman("Katarzyna Nasidlak", 1985, "expert");
    company.addEmployee(e);
    e = new Executive("Mieczyslaw Slabuszewski", 1979);
    company.addEmployee(e);
    
    
    System.out.println("Company name: " + company.getName());
    System.out.println("Number of employees: " + Employee.count);
    System.out.println("Company payroll: " + company.computePayRoll() + " euros");

}

}
```

```js
public class Company{

private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList <Employee>();

private String name;

public Company(final String name) {
  //TODO
 this.name = name;
}


public void addEmployee(Employee e) {
 employees.add(e);
}

public int computePayRoll() {
 
}

public String getName() {
 
    return this.name;
}

}
```

```js
public class Executive extends Employee {

public Executive(final String name, int year) {
  //TODO
 super(name,year);
}

@Override
public void calculateSalary() {
  //TODO
 
}

}
```

```js
public class Workman extends Employee {

private static final String CATEGORY_EXPERT = "expert";

private String category;

public Workman(final String name, int incorporationYear, final String category) {
  //TODO
 super(name,incorporationYear);
 this.category = category;
}

@Override
public void calculateSalary() {
  //TODO

}
}
```

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta está planteada de forma muy amplia, ¿por qué no te concentras en tu función `calculateSalary` solamente? Puedes, por ejemplo, imprimir registros en la consola para asegurar que la estás llamando correctamente, pero tu pregunta debe ser específica y el código que agregues debe ilustrar correctamente el problema. Poner todo tu código, incluyendo el que no está relacionado, crea mas confusión que claridad.

Comment: Dentro del método _calculateSalary_ de la clase _**Executive**_ simplemente agregas `return 2000;`. Y en el mismo método pero dentro de la clase _**Workman**_ agregas `return 1000;`. Por último dentro del método _computePayRoll_ de la clase _**Company**_ recorres los empleados que tienes cargados en _employees_ acumulando el _calculateSalary_ de cada uno y devuelves el valor acumulado. Perdón si no entendí, pero ¿es esa tu duda?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tendrías que tener un get() para obtener el salario en la clase empleado, luego de esto en el método "computePayRoll()" deberías de recorrer la lista de empleados que tienes he ir sumado los sueldos,teniendo en cuenta que tienes un método get() para obtener el sueldo.

Comment: Hola Diego, te invito a que leas [answer] para que puedas redactar buenas respuestas, por que no agregar un ejemplo en código para mayor facilidad de entendimiento? En este caso tu respuesta parece más un comentario podrías mejorarla por medio de una edición siguiendo las bases del link que te acabo de pasar, saludos !

Comment: Gracias por contestar,
Esto lo entiendo, lo que no puedo llegar a entender, es como creo el salario de cada empleado si no me lo entran por main, como se puede ver, ya que el numeor es solo una Data. A lo que me refiero pues, es que el sueldo se calcula a partir de manera "automatica" pues el sueldo base de cada Workman es de 1000 y el de cada Executive es de 2000, por lo que vendria por "defecto" y no entrado.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que automáticamente tengas el salario de los diferentes tipos de de empleado, lo que tienes que hacer es crear un propiedad (atributo) salario en la clase "Employee".Luego sobrescribes el get y set (en las clases que heredan de "Employee")  de salario y en el constructor puedes llamar el al set y poner la cantidad que quiera ponerle al salario y cuando creas el nuevo objeto tendrás el salario. Ojala te ayude